# Label Markers on rollover

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3

brand new here.....don't hurt me :).  I also apologize if my terminology is incorrect.
I have no `HTML` experience but come here via `FileMaker`.  I'm working on a FileMaker database just for my own small business and came across `Geocoding`, which I added to my database.  Everything works fine.  But I'm trying to figure out where in the HTML I could change the parameters so **when I roll over a marker I can see the** `Customer's name`, and not just "`Marker 1`".  I was able to adjust the document so when I click on the marker, `Name`, `Address`, `City State`, etc. all pop up, but **can't seem to figure out the** `marker (label?) part`.  If this is too much to ask, I apologize, and could you please just point me in the right direction.

I've been on this site and a few others over the past week, just reading & trying to learn all I can, and tinkering, but still remain stumped.

Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.  Of course if you need any more info just please ask.

Thanks
Steve

PS Please note the below `HTML` is not something I created, just imported to my `DB` solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?                     sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
   var myOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.52863469527167,2.43896484375),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,     google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID]
    }
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var markerBounds    = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var markers         = new Array(
    [[MarkersArray]]
    );

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;    

function addMarker(options){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map:map});
    marker.setOptions(options);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(marker['info']);

        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    markerBounds.extend(options.position);

    return marker;
}

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.close();
});

var end = markers.length;
for(var i=0; i<end; i++) {
    addMarker({
        position: markers[i]['position'],
        title: "Marker "+i,
        info: markers[i]['info']
    });
}

map.setCenter(markerBounds.getCenter());
map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "title" of the marker is what is displayed on mouseover.  It is being set by this code:

```
addMarker({
    position: markers[i]['position'],
    title: "Marker "+i,
    info: markers[i]['info']
});
```

Change the "Marker "+i to be the text you want displayed.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I think I needed to add a little more info to my original question.  Instead of  "Marker  " + i, I want it to extract the customers names from the database and have that show as I roll over each pin. So the follow up question should be, how do I set that variable (if that's the right term).

Comment: Then you will need to provide more context. What is in MarkersArray?  How is it being populated from your database?  Does it currently include the customer's name?

Comment: Thanks for your follow up.  The MarkersArray is a custom function in FileMaker. Also info & source are 2 unstored calculations. If I could figure out how to attach a screenshot, I think that may help.

Comment: Anyone......anyone?  Does anyone have any advice or need me to provide some more info?  Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just set the marker's title to the customers name when you construct it.  That should do what you need.  You don't have enough information in your question to provide code to do that...

Comment: Thanks for your reply geocodezip.  That is what I've been trying to do, with no luck.  Was the dropbox file helpful?  If not, what more info could I provide that may get me an answer? I've been researching and fiddling, but can't seem to get it to display customer name or rollover.  Should I be looking at tooltip?  Which I found no info on the developers website.
Thanks

Comment: I don't find pictures useful. If the "customer's name" is in the MarkersArray, pass it into the call to addMarker (instead of setting the title to "Marker "+i, set it to that value).

Comment: Well thanks for trying to help me geocodezip.  I'm just a FileMaker guy with not enough experience to make this happen. "Customer's Name" is in the MarkersArray, but I just don't understand how to change the code "..pass it into the call to addMarker...like you recommend.  No worries, I'll keep on trying to learn...Thanks again :)

Comment: How is it stored in the MarkersArray?  I don't see it in the picture you posted.

Comment: I apologize, I just don't know how to answer your question.  I initially thought it was a "....change 'this' to 'that' kind of thing".  I continue educating myself until I can provide more info.