# How to display dynamic marker label info from database

Tags: arrays, google-maps-api-3, filemaker, label, markers

For the past month or so I have been trying to solve this problem.  I checked the website extensively, including all tutorials I could find, and even bought a book. I previously posted but have had no luck.  Hopefully I have more info to get some help.
Basically I have a map in my FileMaker database.  Everything works fine, except for one thing I would like to change.  When I roll over each marker I would like to see the label show the customers name, instead of the static "Marker 1", "Marker 2", etc.
I included a link to dropbox that has the html, the MarkersArray custom function and hopefully all the info that's passed to the Html that may be needed.  Through much trial and *terror*, I can't figure out how to make it happen.  Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Steve

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71328624/GoogleMapsDocs/html.txt
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71328624/GoogleMapsDocs/ss1geo.png

Comment: 2 other links https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71328624/GoogleMapsDocs/calcs.png https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71328624/GoogleMapsDocs/MarkersArraySS.png

Answer (score 0):

instantiate a variable that calculates the company name inside of your for loop. replace "Marker" +i with the variable.

Comment: Viking...I appreciate the reply..I'm just not a google maps guy so I don't know how to do what you suggested.  Ive tried and tried. The array does get all the info for the info window (in the 'info' calculation), can I not pull the Marker title out of that somehow?  Any continued help is greatly appreciated  Here's a link to a previous thread that has the code in it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410892/label-markers-on-rollover